# Binding UI-element to UI-element like Textbox to Textbox

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have UI-elements like a textbox and I want to bind them to a ViewModel. I need to access many properties of the textbox like the text- or the IsEnabled-property. 
Is it possible that I bind the textbox directly to another textbox in the ViewModel with all their properties instead of binding every single property to properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, using an `ElementName`, but you still bind all properties though.

```
<!-- Bound to ViewModel -->
<TextBox Name="tbOne" IsEnabled="{Binding OneIsEnabled}" Text={Binding TextOne}/>

<TextBox Name="tbTwo" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=tbOne, Path=IsEnabled}" Text={Binding ElementName=tbOne, Path=Text}/>
```

There is no built-in way to bind all dependency properties of the TextBox to another. Personally, I would prefer binding directly to the ViewModel.

An alternative solution would be to create a UserControl that internally clones the TextBox with all bindings:

```
<CloneControl Target="{Binding ElementName=tbOne}"/>
```

Here, the ControlControl would inspect the target, and have code that create a new TextBox, and sets the bindings in code. This is only useful if you are doing this very often, and there is a slightly performance price to pay, as you are adding another level of controls to the UI tree.